# how to add new object to an existing json data

Tags: json, reactjs, forms

so i am trying to go through this project and i have these data from json using api:

[image: json data]

so basically i got the data from the api, loaded them locally and now i have created this form using useForm:

[image: form]

so what i'm doing is that i want the form to take these data and add them to the existing json data that have been loaded internally how can i do that? i'm really stuck and no idea how to do it

my loading json code:

```
const [photo,setPhoto] = useState([])
    const newPhotosLocally = photo

    newPhotosLocally.forEach((item,i) =>{
        item.photoId = i +1;
    })

    console.log(newPhotosLocally)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(
            result => {
                setPhoto(result.data)
            }
        )
    },[])
```

my form code:

```
const {register,handleSubmit,errors} = useForm();

        const onSubmit = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            newPhotosLocally.push([data])

        };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="link" name="link" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="thumbnail url" name="thumbnail" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title" ref={register}/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
```

Comment: This is an array, you will have to iterate over this array and then with each iteration, parse the Json to get the required fields. If this doesn't suffice your requirement, please specify more on where is the issue for more understanding

Comment: if you can see i have a form so what i want is when i enter the three information in the form, the data entered will be added to the json data i don't need to parse the original json to get the data i just need to add the new data to the json data in the correct format which i'm not able to do

Comment: can you share your JSON in which you want to add the data(the one you mentioned at the start of the question)

Comment: @codeogeek i have created a sandbox please tell me if its working and hope you can help: https://codesandbox.io/live/R6Q7X0

Comment: @codeogeek again if you can see i have got the data using axios and stored them using useState photo inside newPhotosLocally, the i have a form which i want to take the data from and save them inside newPhotosLocally in the correct format

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're only taking 3 values in your form, and I assume that album id and id you'll pass using some random logic.
Your JSON object is ideally array of objects,
so when you take input from your form, create the object with that data like this,

```
const obj={albumId:'1', id:'2', photoId:'2', title:'abcd', thumbnailUrl:'https://abcd.com', url:'https://abcd.com'}
```

Take your initial JSON big data in a variable,

```
const originalJSON = <your original data>
const parsedData = JSON.parse(originalJSON);
parsedData.push(obj);
originalJSON = JSON.Stringify(parsedData);
```

Hope this helps!!